# (node:31436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I don`t know but i caught error how to fix it?

```
async execute(message, args) {
        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send('Укажи название песни.');
        if (!message.member || !message.member.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('Нужно зайти в голосовой канал.');

        const query = args.join(' ');
        const [song] = await bot.getSongs(`ytsearch: ${query}`);


        if (!song) return message.channel.send('Ничего не найдено...');

        const player = await bot.player.join({
            guild: message.guild.id,
            channel: message.member.voiceChannelID,
            host: bot.player.nodes.first().host
        }, {selfdeaf: true});

        if (!player) return message.channel.send('Я не могу зайти в канал.');

        player.play(song.track);

        player.once('error', () => {});
        player.once('end', async data => {
            if (data.reason === 'REPLACED') return;
            message.channel.send(`Песня **${song.info.title}** закончилась.`);
            await bot.player.leave(message.guild.id);
        });

        return message.channel.send(`Сейчас играет: **${song.info.title}**`);
    }
```

Error: (node:31436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable

Comment: You should surround your function body in a `try catch` block. But looks like `const [song] = await bot.getSongs(`ytsearch: ${query}`);` is not returning an array. Try logging the resolved value from this promise.

Answer (score 0):

@Utkarsh is right.

I just met same problem when I use Blubird's `PromisifyAll` to add async function for `request` pacakge.

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';
import request from 'request';

const requestAsync = Promise.promisifyAll(request);


async function x() {
  const [_res, body] = await requestAsync.getAsync({
    uri: 'http://google.com',
  });
}
```

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable` occurred all because `requestAsync.getAsync` is not returning an array.

Try to assign to a single variable or consider other kind of async function, in my situation, it's:

```
const requestAsync = Promise.promisifyAll(request, { multiArgs: true });
```